# SQL Search for Data in Multiple Columns

Tags: sql

Dears,

I have a table as shown below as a sample, and I want to run one query by which i can find all the yellow highlighted ones by using  %AAA%.

Instead of running the Where command on each column one by one, I can do one general find option and it will list all the rows.

Thank you in advance!!

[image: Sample Data image]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server then you can write dynamic query to do so. Please try below query:

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select * from [TableName] where ' 
    + stuff((
            select ' or  [' + [column_name] + '] like ''%AAA%''' 
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name = 'TableName'
            for xml path('')
    ) 
    , 1, 5, ''
);

exec(@sql);
```

This query will return every row in which at least one column contains AAA.

Answer (score 0):

You can include all the conditions in one `where` clause using `or`:

```
where col1 like '%aaa%' or
      col2 like '%aaa%' or
      . . .   -- and so on for all the columns
```

Comment: Thanks for this, there are more than 20 col in my database so I'm looking if it's possible to run with one operator?

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the columns and do a `WHERE` based on that:

```sql
select *
from Table
where exists (select 1
    from (values (col1), (col2), (col3) ) AS v (allCols)    -- etc
    where v.allCols like '%aaa%'
);
```

If you can't be bothered to type them out, try this little query:

```sql
select STRING_AGG('(' + c.name + ')', ', ')
from sys.columns c
where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Name_Of_Table_Here');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use its JSON functionality:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t)) as x(col,val)
              where val like '%AAA%');
```

If you are using Postgres 12 or later you can use a SQL/JSON path expression:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where to_jsonb(t) @@ '$.* like_regex "AAA" flag "i"'
```