# SQL Statement to search a keyword in all the columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can anyone suggest a select statement in mySQL(Workbench) where i can find a particular keyword in any of the column available in a table.

For ex. 'Stocks' , i don't know whether its in Col 1, Col2, Col3 ...

so a generic code to search everywhere ??

**Im a beginner**

Comment: There isn't one. You have to explicitly specify all of the column names.

Comment: This may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/a/66081358/14868997 It's for SQL Server, but you should be able to adapt to MySQL if you are on version 8.0+

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: Do you need the name(s) of column(s) which contains the keyword, or "present in this row" is enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE
col1 LIKE '%Stocks%' OR
col2 LIKE '%Stocks%' OR
col3 LIKE '%Stocks%' OR
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all coumn names, you can go easy way:

```
SELECT * FROM !your_table!
WHERE column1 LIKE '%Stocks%' OR
column2 LIKE '%Stocks%' OR
column3 LIKE '%Stocks%'
```

But if not, you need prepared query, there has no easy way.

```
SET @generic_query = (
  SELECT CONCAT("SELECT * FROM !your_table! WHERE CONCAT_WS(\'~\',", (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`')) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '!your_table!' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '!your_table_schema!'
  ), ") LIKE '%Stocks%';"));
PREPARE generic_q FROM @generic_query;
EXECUTE generic_q;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE generic_q;
```